# ¿Cómo obtener tamaño de archivo?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $size_img = $_FILES['img1']['size'];
    echo $size_img;
}
```

Lo que sucede es que quiero obtener el tamaño del archivo que se envía al servidor pero solo me da como resultado 0.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: muestra el código como envías `img1`...

Comment: Muchas veces, los problemas con datos enviados al servidor, los resuelves iterando entre las variables que recibes. Haz un `foreach` o un `print_r` en `$_FILES` y así puedes ver todas las variables que estás enviando. Verifica también que el fichero se esté subiendo correctamente y que `img1` sea su nombre.

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿estás subiendo más de un fichero?

Answer (score 2):

Veamos un ejemplo como podría quedar, también he puesto opcional, si uno desea crear unas reglas, es decir, validar si la *extensión*, *tamaño*, *ancho*, *alto*, etc.… de nuestra imagen cumple con la configuración que vamos a añadir.

**formulario HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="control_imagen.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Subir imagen</label>
   <input type="file" name="img1" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar" />
</form>
```

**control_imagen.php**

```
   <?php
//Comprobamos si esta definido y no NULL nuestro formulario.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Comprobamos que no este vacio nuestro input file.
    if (!file_exists($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo 'Es obligatorio seleccionar una imagen para continuar.';
    } else {
        //Obtenemos valor de la imagen.
        $file = $_FILES["img1"];
        //Obtenemos tamaño imagen.
        $tamano_img = $file["size"];
        //Imprimimos tamaño.    
        echo "Tamaño imagen: $tamano_img";

        //otra opción,seria un sistema de comprobaciones ///

        //Obtenemos otros datos de interés para nuestra imagen.
        $nombre_img = $file["name"];        
        $extencion_img = $file["type"];
        $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_temporal);
        $ancho = $dimensiones[0];
        $altura = $dimensiones[1];
        $ruta_temporal = $file["tmp_name"];
        $carpeta = "./tu_destino/";

        //Creamos reglas de configuración para nuestra imagen.
        if ($extencion_img != 'image/jpeg' && $extencion_img != 'image/jpg' && $extencion_img != 'image/png' && $extencion_img != 'image/gif') {
            echo "Ups! <b>$nombre_img</b>, no es una imagen valido, un imagen con extensión valido podría ser entre (.jpg, .jpeg, .png o .gif).";                     
        } elseif($tamano_img > 300000) {
            echo"Ups! El tamaño de tu imagen <b>$nombre_img</b>, supera los 300kb permitidos.";
        } else if($ancho > 500 || $altura > 500) {
            echo "Ups! La anchura y la altura de <b>$nombre_img</b> supera la máxima permitida de 500px."; 

        } else if($ancho < 250 || $altura < 250) {
                echo "Ups! La anchura y la altura de <b>$nombre_img</b> es inferior que la mínima permitida de 250px.";             
        } else {
            //Si la configuración es correcto, seguimos con nuestro código.
        }       
    }
}
?>
```